# rails api dock syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-doc

ROR Api Dock always starts with a syntax of the method.  My example will be link_to:

`link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block) public`

My question is on the `"name=nil"` or `"something = nil"` which i see on most every command.

A second example:  `url_for(options = nil)`

Can someone explain what is the point of this or what it is trying to say..does it mean that the option is optional?

Why is it important..

Comment: It means that it also accepts `nil` for that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby unlike for example JavaScript or PHP enforces the number of arguments a method is called with:

```
def foo(a,b) 
end
```

So if you call `foo` with no arguments Ruby will raise an exception `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`.

By setting a default value, you mark a argument as optional:

```
def foo(a = nil, b = nil) 
end
```

Calling `foo` with no arguments will no longer raise an error.

This is often used to create methods that can take list arguments or a hash:

```
def foo(a = nil, b = nil, opts = {})
  opts.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{k} : #{v}"
  end
end
```

As to why Ruby does this - its a language design decision. It does in many cases help track down simple bugs where you are simply passing the wrong arguments. In a language that does not enforce this you would get a type or undefined error from inside the method which is harder to spot the root cause of. IMHO [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) got this one right.